# Python - How can I plot a line graph properly with a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, line-plot

I am trying to plot a line graph to show the trends of each key of a dictionary in Jupyter Notebook with Python. This is what I have in the k_rmse_values variable as shown below:

> k_rmse_values = 
>   {'bore': {1: 8423.759328233446,
>     3: 6501.928933614838,
>     5: 6807.187615513473,
>     7: 6900.29659028346,
>     9: 7134.8868708101645},
>    'city-mpg': {1: 4265.365592771621,
>     3: 3865.0178306330113,
>     5: 3720.409335758634,
>     7: 3819.183283405616,
>     9: 4219.677972675927},
>    'compression-rate': {1: 7016.906657495168,
>     3: 7319.354017489066,
>     5: 6301.624922763969,
>     7: 6133.006310754547,
>     9: 6417.253959732598},
>    'curb-weight': {1: 3950.9888180049306,
>     3: 4201.343428000144,
>     5: 4047.052502155118,
>     7: 3842.0974736649846,
>     9: 3943.9478256384205},
>    'engine-size': {1: 2853.7338453331627,
>     3: 2793.6254775629623,
>     5: 3123.320055069605,
>     7: 2941.73029681235,
>     9: 2931.996240628853},
>    'height': {1: 6330.178232877807,
>     3: 7049.500497198366,
>     5: 6869.570862695864,
>     7: 6738.641089739572,
>     9: 6344.062937760911},
>    'highway-mpg': {1: 4826.0580187146525,
>     3: 3510.253629329685,
>     5: 3379.2250123364083,
>     7: 4044.271135312068,
>     9: 4462.027046251678},
>    'horsepower': {1: 3623.6389886411143,
>     3: 4294.825669466819,
>     5: 4778.254807521257,
>     7: 4730.538701514935,
>     9: 4662.8601512508885},
>    'length': {1: 4952.798701744297,
>     3: 5403.624431188139,
>     5: 5500.731909846179,
>     7: 5103.4515274528885,
>     9: 4471.077661709427},
>    'normalized-losses': {1: 9604.929081466453,
>     3: 7494.820436511842,
>     5: 6391.912634697067,
>     7: 6699.853883298577,
>     9: 6861.6389834002875},
>    'peak-rpm': {1: 8041.2366213164005,
>     3: 7502.080095843049,
>     5: 6521.863037752326,
>     7: 6869.602542315512,
>     9: 6884.533017667794},
>    'stroke': {1: 10330.231237489314,
>     3: 8947.585146097614,
>     5: 6973.912792744113,
>     7: 7266.333478250421,
>     9: 7026.017456146411},
>    'wheel-base': {1: 2797.4144312203725,
>     3: 3392.8627620671928,
>     5: 4238.25624378706,
>     7: 4456.687059524217,
>     9: 4426.032222634904},
>    'width': {1: 2849.2691940215127,
>     3: 4076.59327053035,
>     5: 3979.9751617315405,
>     7: 3845.3326184519606,
>     9: 3687.926625900343}}

When I used this code to plot

```
for k,v in k_rmse_values.items():
x = list(v.keys())
y = list(v.values())

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('k value')
plt.ylabel('RMSE')
```

and it doesn't plot from 1 to 9 in order; it gives this graph
[image]

it plots in this k-value order 1, 3, 9 , 5, 7

I have spent hours on this problem and still can't figure out a way to do it. Your help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remember that a regular dictionary in python does NOT have any order to it, regardless of how you enter the data.  So when you are plotting points using `plt.plot()`, it is just going from (x, y) to next point in the order presented.  You want to make pairs of these key-values, probably by zipping them, and then sort them by the x coordinate.  You could probably pull the keys from the main dictionary and put them into labels for a legend pretty easily in your loop

Comment: @JeffH Alternatively sort `v.entries()` instead of zipping.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to sort the keys and get the matching values:

```
for k,v in k_rmse_values.items():
  xs = list(v.keys()).sort()
  ys = [v[x] for x in xs]

# Note I renamed these arrays so following uses should be changed accordingly
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have received this error when I implemented your code.


TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e10e7d10e316> in <module>()
      4 for k,v in k_rmse_values.items():
      5     xs = list(v.keys()).sort()
----> 6     ys = [v[x] for x in xs]
      7 
      8     plt.plot(xs,ys)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @ting-c Please post a new question with a complete code example. This will allow you to format it correctly. Please be sure to include the error message as well.